# Callback error on YouTube socialite provider for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, youtube, laravel-socialite

I am trying to set up Oauth with the YouTube Data API. I had a Laravel app which has Socialite set up. Out of the box YouTube isn't set up with this but I saw that there is a provider for YouTube here:

https://socialiteproviders.netlify.app/providers/you-tube.html

I have done all of the steps outlined on the page along with all routes that I need. I have also done the Oauth set up on Google Developer Console and got the client ID/secret key and set the callback.

When I use the login URL it works where I'm redirected for login with Google. The problem comes when the callback URL is reached. I get the error:

**ErrorException
Undefined index: items**

This occurs on the provider callback function which has the code:

`$user = Socialite::driver('youtube')->user();`

I have tried using stateless:

`$user = Socialite::driver('youtube')->stateless()->user();`

But get the same error. All caches have been cleared. I am pretty sure that the setup was done correctly as I'm also using the Twitch provider from https://socialiteproviders.netlify.app/providers/twitch.html which the setup was similar and it works correctly.

Please can anyone advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the fields you want to access first:

```php
$user = Socialite::driver('youtube')->fields([
                    'items'
                ])->user();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. Is it possible that the API has changed? If I take a look at the raw response there

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled onto this issue:
When I tested it, I did not got the error, but my colleague did so I figured it had something to do with the account that tried to connect.

I changed my approach from:

```
$user = Socialite::driver('youtube')->stateless()->user();
```

And just received tokens by doing this:

```
$socialite = Socialite::driver('youtube');
$code      = $request->input('code');
$response  = $socialite->getAccessTokenResponse($code);
```

`$response` will contain an array of tokens. I used these tokens to connect it to an existing user in my database.

I don't know if this is the solution for your workflow, but it is a way to get around the mysterious error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to YouTube no longer automatically creating a channel for your google/gmail account like it did in the past. This results in responses completely missing an items array.

if you `dd($response->getBody()->getContents())` the response for an account that throws an error you'll see this.

[image]

I've made a pull request for this here. https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/YouTube/pull/8